# Box2d body movement in Andengine

Tags: android, box2d, andengine

I made a race game.there are car.it is moving by onAnalogScreenContol button.And it's moving perfect what i set velocity to its body.But when i add 50 walls which are Shape of rectangle and body,the car moving very very fast.How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Please provide some code snippets of how you create your world

Answer (score 0):

Perhaphs having a look at the code to my racing game will help you:
http://sebastiannilsson.com/en/k/projekt/sketchy-truck/

Source code is hosted on Github. It will give you an example of how to do a racing game in Android. I do not know how similar it is to your game though.